# It seems css style didn't work for the TreeData of ag-Grid

Tags: angular, ag-grid

Follow the tutorials [Tree Data](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-tree-data/), I created one angular project according to sample in the ag-Grid tree data website(https://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:e5gDneScpWFRIwj48PEz), but I really don't know how to correctly display the sample, it looks like the css didn't work for me, I modified the code many times, but can't solve this issue.

Could someone provide some help for me? Any helps will be appreciated.

In the angular project. I have installed the package **ag-grid-angular, ag-grid-community, ag-grid-enterprise, @ag-grid-community/all-modules and @ag-grid-enterprise/all-modules** in the node_modules

In the app.module.ts file

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
import { HttpClientModule } from "@angular/common/http";

import { AgGridModule } from "@ag-grid-community/angular";
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
  AppComponent
],
imports: [
  BrowserModule,
  FormsModule,
  HttpClientModule,
  AgGridModule.withComponents([])
],
providers: [],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

In the app.component.ts file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AllModules, Module } from "@ag-grid-enterprise/all-modules";

import "@ag-grid-community/all-modules/dist/styles/ag-grid.css";
import "@ag-grid-community/all-modules/dist/styles/ag-theme-balham.css";
....
```

the left code is same as the URL https://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:e5gDneScpWFRIwj48PEz, please see the code in there.

I saw the solution someone answered that put the ag-grid.css and ag-theme-balham.css in the styles.scss file, but when I put them in the styles.scss, ran the project, the result page showed nothing, and there is no error thrown.

My result likes below:
[image]

As shown above snapshot, it looks like the css styles didn't work, the layout is a mess.

Comment: in your styles.scss file import below both line `@import "~ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css";
@import "~ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-balham.css";`

Comment: look at this link https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-grid/#add-ag-grid-to-your-project

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I had put these two css files in the styles.scss previous days, but when I put them in the styles.scss, the page showed nothing after run the project, the page is blank.